# Lashon Hora to get something off one's chest'?

Tags: halacha, lashon-hara-slander, bein-adam-lachavero

Is there an issue of Lashon Hora to tell someone about a difficult situation that one is experiencing with another person if your purpose is to vent and get 'something off one's chest'? Similarly, may one discuss such a situation with a mentor who can give advice on how to manage the situation?

To be clear, this is not a case ח"ו of abuse or something that should require therapy.